# An integral that wolfram apparently can't solve

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

Is it possible to represent this integral in terms of elementary functions?

$$\int \textrm{ln}(1+e^{x^{2}})dx$$

I saw a challenge on this site ([integral challenge](http://durofy.com/5-most-beautiful-questions-from-integral-calculus/)) and still can not figure out how to solve it (if it's solvable).

**Addition**

The full integral (the one I want to calculate) is $$\int \left [\textrm{ln}(1+e^{x^{2}})+2\frac{[e^{x^{2}}(2x^{2}-1)-1]}{(e^{x^{2}}+1)^{2}}\right ]dx$$

Perhaps combining the two terms gives rise to an elementary primitive.

Comment: This post about elementary integrals may be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral

Comment: For $|x|\gg 0$ the integrand function essentially is $x^2$, so the primitive is close to $\frac{x^3}{3}$. Then you may use Leucippus' approach with a minor twist to write to full asymptotic expansion through the error function.

Answer (score 2):

One method may be to expand the logarithm as seen by:
\begin{align}
\int \ln(1 + e^{x^2}) \, dx &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \, \int e^{n \, x^2} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n \, \sqrt{n}} \, erfi(\sqrt{n} \, x),
\end{align}
where $erfi(x)$ is the imaginary error function.

Comment: That's interesting. The full integral have a second term, as you can see in the link. I was thinking of doing some combination between the ln and this term to get a primitive.